# Update app widget every minute not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appwidget

I need to show a countdown timer in the app and I need to do it with widgets. Since the counter is an hour counter, it must be updated every minute. I get the time to countdown from SQL database. I wrote my appWidget codes for this. It works fine for the first few minutes but after that the counter does not continue. The solutions I found on the internet are very old and not working.

My codes are as follows;
`PrayerTimeWidget3.class`:

```
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                    int appWidgetId) {

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.prayer_time_widget3 );
            ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName( context, PrayerTimeWidget3.class );

            // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget( watchWidget, views );
        }


@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        _scheduleNextUpdate( context );
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget( context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId );
        }


    }


    private static void _scheduleNextUpdate(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager =
                (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );
        Intent intent = new Intent( context, PrayerTimeWidget3.class )
                .setAction( ACTION_SCHEDULED_UPDATE3 );
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( context, 0, intent, 0 );

        // Schedule to update when convenient for the system, will not wakeup device
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle( AlarmManager.RTC, 60000, pendingIntent );
        } else
            alarmManager.set( AlarmManager.RTC, 60000, pendingIntent );
    }
```

prayer_time_widget3_info.xml:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/prayer_time_widget3"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/prayer_time_widget3"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="90dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ptwidget3preview"

    android:updatePeriodMillis="60000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".PrayerTimeWidget3">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/prayer_time_widget3_info" />
        </receiver>
```

I would be glad if you help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a [`Chronometer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer) instead? It'll handle updating itself, and `RemoteViews` has [methods specifically for it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setChronometer(int,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)).

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for your comment. I get the time from the database and count down by subtracting the current time from the time I got. So can I use the Chronometer with the appWidget? Does it work even if the app is closed? Will it continue to show??

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Thread Class of Java.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // delay of 1 sec after every update
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            // Update Here!
                            
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```